# Javascript - Convert 1 to true (With example)

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON and I want to convert FUTURE_CALL to true if the value is 1, 0 to false.

How can I do this? My example does not work.

```
var tickets = '{tickets: {
   "Tickets": [
      {
         "TICKET_ID": "",
         "TITLE": "",
         "DESCRIPTION": "",
         "CREATION_DATE": "",
         "COMPLETION_DATE": "",
         "CREATED_BY": "",
         "FUTURE_CALL": "",
         "TICKET_PRIORITY_DESCRIPTION": "",
         "TICKET_PRIORITY_CODE": "",
         "TICKET_CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION": "",
         "TICKET_CATEGORY_CODE": "",
         "TICKET_TYPE_CODE": "",
         "TICKET_TYPE_DESCRIPTION": "",
         "TICKET_TAG_CODE": "",
         "TICKET_TAG_DESCRIPTION": "",
         "TICKET_STATUS_CODE": "",
         "TICKET_STATUS_DESCRIPTION": "",
         "DUE_DATE": "",
         "ACCOUNT_ID": ""
      }
   ]
}}';

var updatedTickets = tickets;
for(var i = 0; i < updatedTickets.tickets['Tickets'].length; i++) {
     if(updatedTickets[i].tickets['Tickets'].FUTURE_CALL == 1) {
        updatedTickets[i].tickets['Tickets'].FUTURE_CALL = true;
     }
}
```

Comment: just press run code ??

Comment: user10031499, **please read:** [What should you do when someone answers your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

At first there is a small problem in your code:

```
updatedTickets[i].tickets['Tickets']
```

`updatedTiclets` is an object, its `tickets['Tickets"]` that is an array, so you have to:

```
updatedTickets.tickets['Tickets'][i]
```

Then your comparison should work, but the easiest is just to convert it to a number:

```
if( +updatedTickets.tickets['Tickets'][i].FUTURE_CALL)
```

That will work as `0` is falsey and `1` is truthy.

```
var updatedTickets = tickets;
for(const ticket of updatedTickets.tickets['Tickets']) k
 ticket.FUTURE_CALL =
     ticket.FUTURE_CALL === "1";        
}
```

Comment: I cant even loop the JSON array correctly. I need to loop ( I know in this example is only one) and change all FUTURE_CALLS. Please do this

Answer (score 0):

1. At first you have not valide JSON – you have to write `{"tickets":` and not `{tickets:` (like in your code).
2. Then you have to use `JSON.parse` to parse JSON.
3. And then you have to use backslash on each new line in your JSON string if you want to write it in one string.
4. `updatedTickets[i].tickets['Tickets']` is wrong. You have to write `updatedTickets.tickets['Tickets'][i]`.

I corrected your code:

```js
var tickets = '{"tickets": {\
    "Tickets": [\
    {\
        "TICKET_ID": "",\
        "TITLE": "",\
        "DESCRIPTION": "",\
        "CREATION_DATE": "",\
        "COMPLETION_DATE": "",\
        "CREATED_BY": "",\
        "FUTURE_CALL": "",\
        "TICKET_PRIORITY_DESCRIPTION": "",\
        "TICKET_PRIORITY_CODE": "",\
        "TICKET_CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION": "",\
        "TICKET_CATEGORY_CODE": "",\
        "TICKET_TYPE_CODE": "",\
        "TICKET_TYPE_DESCRIPTION": "",\
        "TICKET_TAG_CODE": "",\
        "TICKET_TAG_DESCRIPTION": "",\
        "TICKET_STATUS_CODE": "",\
        "TICKET_STATUS_DESCRIPTION": "",\
        "DUE_DATE": "",\
        "ACCOUNT_ID": ""\
    }]\
}}';

var updatedTickets = JSON.parse(tickets),
 ticketsObj = updatedTickets.tickets['Tickets'];

for(var i = 0; i < ticketsObj.length; i++)
    // symbol "+" convert string to integer
 ticketsObj[i].FUTURE_CALL = +ticketsObj[i].FUTURE_CALL == 1 ? true : false;

console.log(JSON.stringify(updatedTickets, null, '\t'));
```